# What happens in the final battle of Underworld between the Human Army and the Dark Territory Army?

Tags: sword-art-online

I was unfortunately unable to be a part of the group that got to read the web novels before they were taken down, but it's killing me ever since I finished LN 15.  There are so many unresolved questions that I have and I can't seem to even find a release date for the Japanese version of Volume 16, let alone the English version, so if you read the web novel, can you enlighten me on a few points that are driving me crazy?

- At the end of LN 14 when the power surge hits Kirito's FL, it seems to rip a hole in his consciousness and even the crying out of Asuna only seems to bring nostalgia, but he can't seem to place why he knows that voice?  Is that what happened?
- Alice seems to be following a similar train of thought to Kirito from the original SAO arc, that if the **** hit the fan, she's going to run with Kirito for the World End Altar?  What would happen if she and Kirito do make it there?  Kirito could log out, but she can't?
- Not that I want to seem like a shipper, but the relationships in this storyline are frustrating because I can't decide who to root for.  It's almost like Reki is opening the chance for Kirito to stay with Alice instead of returning to the real world?
- How does Kirito get his consciousness back?
- Given the side stories that have been released, it seems that the battle comes to a close with a truce?  Is that true for the main storyline?
- Does anyone have any info on release dates?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm asking for *spoilers* but I want to be spoiled, so please spoil me!!!!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any information about vol 16 on Wikipedia Japanese, so I guess we don't really know